# How to differentiate between H.264 bitstream and HEVC bitstream?

Tags: parsing, h.264, codec, multimedia, hevc

I have two parsers to parse h.264 and HEVC bit stream.When I get a bit stream how can I differentiate between the bitstream so that I can use the correct parser.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

For H.264 you are looking for:

```
(0x00) 0x00 0x00 0x01 [Access Unit Delimiter]

Where Access Unit Delimiter must be: (byte & 0x1f) == 0x09
```

For H.265 you are looking for

```
(0x00) 0x00 0x00 0x01 [Access Unit Delimiter | VPS | SPS]

Where Access Unit Delimiter must be: (byte >> 1 & 0x3f) == 0x23 or
VPS must: (byte >> 1 & 0x3f) == 0x20 or 
SPS must: (byte >> 1 & 0x3f) == 0x21
```

Comment: You can't rely on AUDs, they are not mandatory in h264 and also not mandatory in h265

Comment: While this is technically correct that you can leave out the NAL of type access unit delimiter.
I rarely see streams without AU delimiters - assuming AnnexB.

The standards describe in great detail how you can detect the start of an Access Unit and in most cases it is the AU delimiter.

Comment: Most files encoded by Apple products don't have AUDs. I'm dealing with this issue right now and try to find a way to differentiate between h264 and h265 without AUDs. Originally I did it with AUDs but it is not working anymore with the files I'm dealing with now.

Comment: Apple writes files into MOVs then the H.264(5) are NOT in AnnexB and should not contain AU delimiters.
Once you have a MOV container - you can just look at the sample description and then get the video format.

Comment: True, but in my workflow I get the demuxed ves files, without AUDs. And for those I'm trying to determine if they are h264 or h265. I don't have access to the original mov file.

Comment: Btw. ffprobe can determine if it is h264 or h265 without AUDs. But I need a way to do it in C by accessing the buffer without calling an external program.

Comment: Your demuxer should insert AU delimiter, PPS and SPS.
Regardless H.264 has different NAL unit types than H.265.
So for H.264 look for PPS, SPS and IDR frame
For H.265 look for VPS, SPS and IDR

Comment: It doesn't insert AUDs. FFMPEG for example also doesn't insert AUDs when you demux a mov file, even with the command line option `-x264opts aud=1`
Yeah I'll probably have to implement a detection algorithm that takes into account more than just the first NAL unit. Thanks for your help

Comment: -x264opts aud=1 is a configuration option when you encode to H.264 using the x264 encoder./
This won't do anything if you copy (demux) a video stream out of a MOV file.

Comment: I see. Thanks, I didn't know that. But yeah ffmpeg doesn't add AUDs when demuxing mov files. The  proprietary demuxer upstream from my module doesn't do it either. Hence I need to find some other reliable way to differentiate. Maybe parsing multiple Nal unit headers and seeing which ones are legit NAL types in each code is the only way. Doesn't seem like it is possible just by looking at the NALU header of the first NALU.